# How to sort XML prices using php

Tags: php, xml, sorting

I'm very new to learning how to use XML, I know a few programming languages. I've tried searching for this answer but I get very confused and cannot relate back to how I would implement this in my code. At the moment I would like to be able to sort prices

Here's an example of how it currently looks

[image: Here an example of how it currently looks]

```
<?php
    $xmlFile = "hotel.xml";
    $HTML = "";
    $count = 0;
    $dom = DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);
    $hotel = $dom->getElementsByTagName("hotel"); 

foreach($hotel as $node) 
{ 
    $city = $node->getElementsByTagName("City");
    $city = $city->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $type = $node->getElementsByTagName("Type");
    $type = $type->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $name = $node->getElementsByTagName("Name");
    $name = $name->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $price = $node->getElementsByTagName("Price");
    $price = $price->item(0)->nodeValue;

    if (($type == $_GET["type"]) && ($city == $_GET["city"]) )
    {
        $HTML = $HTML."<br><span>Hotel: ".$name."</span><br><span>Price: ".$price."</span><br>";
        $count++;
    }
} 

if ($count ==0)
{
    $HTML ="<br><span>No hotels available</span>";
}

echo $HTML;   
?>
```

Comment: If you load the hotels first, selecting the ones that match the criteria, then you can sort the array of matches and only after doing that you can then `foreach` over the results and create the HTML for them.

Comment: I understand your logic, that's how I would do it. But I don't know how to actually sort. I don't know what type hotel and node is